# Write a function with different return types in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

How can I re-write this function in OCaml so that it allows the elements of the tuple to have different types

```
let nth i (x,y,z) = 
match i with
 1->x
|2->y
|3->z
|_->raise (Invalid_argument "nth")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that it's not possible. OCaml is strongly and statically typed. A function returns a single type. Since your function returns `x`, `y`, and `z` in different cases, then these must all be the same type.

OCaml types are not like types in the so-called dynamically typed languages. You need to think differently. The benefits are (in my opinion) tremendous.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but you need to fulfill the constraint that all values, returned from the function should be members of one type. The easiest solution is:

```
let nth i (x,y,z) =
  match i with
  | 1 -> `Fst x
  | 2 -> `Snd y
  | 3 -> `Thd z
  | _ -> invalid_arg "nth tuple"
```

The solution demonstrates that you need to address all possible cases for the types of your tuple. Otherwise, your program will not be well-formed, and this contradicts with the static typing. The latter guarantees that your program is well-formed for any input, so that it wont fail in a runtime.

A twin solution, using ordinary ADT instead of polymorphic ones, will look something like this:

```
type ('a,'b,'c) t =
  | Fst of 'a
  | Snd of 'b
  | Thd of 'c

let nth i (x,y,z) =
  match i with
  | 1 -> Fst x
  | 2 -> Snd y
  | 3 -> Thd z
  | _ -> invalid_arg "nth tuple"
```

An exotic solution (not very practible, maybe) that uses GADT to form an existential type will look like this:

```
type t = Dyn : 'a -> t

let nth i (x,y,z) =
  match i with
  | 1 -> Dyn x
  | 2 -> Dyn y
  | 3 -> Dyn z
  | _ -> invalid_arg "nth tuple"
```